# Error to get number of video views with YouTube API

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

How to get current number of viewers for live video with YouTube API?

I can see number of current viewers using request for feed of videos like this:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q={$video_ID}&alt=json
```

It returns me Not correct views, but I change video id < and still sow me error like this :-

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=pwkS-doaft8&alt=json
```

Its must return `6,856` not `23898088`

Is there any solution of this issue?

Comment: Any API call that uses gdata will no longer work. You must migrate to V3 of the API

Comment: i try v3 and same error

Comment: Let's see your v3 try.